# Mac OS X (Big Sur) capybara-webkit installation problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, qt, qt5, capybara-webkit

I have a problem with installation of capybara-webkit gem. Here is part of my test group in gemfile:

```
 group :test do
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
end
```

And when I write 'bundle' on console - it gives me out

```
`"An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.15.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.15.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling."`
```

So I found out that I need to install qt via homebrew. So I go to homebrew-core, wrote 'brew update', than 'cd $( brew --prefix )/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core' ; 'git checkout 9ba3d6ef8891e5c15dbdc9333f857b13711d4e97 Formula/qt@5.5.rb' ; and 'brew install qt@5.5'.
And then it gives me out 'Error: qt@5.5: unknown version :mountain_lion'. I found out that problem may in 'Formula/qt@5.5.rb' where it has string 'depends_on :macos => :mountain_lion'. So I commented it and then when I write 'brew install qt@5.5' - it gives me out another error:

```
 "Error: Failed to download resource "qt@5.5_bottle_manifest""
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

After many attempts, I was able to install `capybara-webkit` by using the steps from https://til.magmalabs.io/posts/529a5ae0ac-other-errors-when-installing-capybara-webkit-gem-m1-mac-big-sur

```sh
brew tap cartr/qt4
brew install qt@4
brew install qt-webkit@2.3
```

The qt5.5 formula gives errors on BigSur, however qt4 seems to install just fine.

After I had all dependencies resolved, a `bundle install` successfully resolved the `capybara-webkit` dependency (1.15.1 was the version I used in `Gemfile`). Also the cucumber tests executed with no problems, which confirmed the fact that capybara-webkit 1.15.1 works with qt4 and qt-webkit@2.3.